# Mercurial-server add permissions to my repository

Tags: mercurial-server

I'm using mercurial-server to manage my repositories in the enterprise server. I created a repository for each user and I wanted each of them could give access to another, ie, each user would have access control to your projects in your repository. But in mercurial-server documentation I see that only administrators can give that kind of access.

Is that way how it works or gives to circumvent it somehow through the mercurial-server or even own mercurial(hg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delegate the access rights management to your users, they would need to have access to the `/hgadmin` repository and they should be able to modify the `/hgadmin/access.conf` file where the fine grained access control is located.

To my knowledge there is no way (yet) to use Mercurial-server to have silos of access-control, where a user could grant access to his/her own repository but not to *other's* repositories. However you should be able to develop such an extension to the system: with a hook that would extract relevant rights from, e.g., `<user-repo>/admin/access.conf` and copy them in a zone where another hook or a cron would select only lines concerning the `<user-repo>` zone (with a sed or perl or whatever you'd like), then update the real `access.conf` file, and finally commit and push it.

Hope it'll help.